# Redirection and showing alerts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I can redirect to a new page but not invoke an alert.

On a `click` event on the submit button I want to get a JavaScript alert message and redirect to a page with some data updated.

The data update and redirection are working. The alert message is not being displayed.

I am aware that I have sql injection issue. I will work on it after I have the alert working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php

ob_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiple Update and Delete Data</title>
    <?php include "header.php"; ?>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#DCE3E7">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm() {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to update these properties?'))
        {
            window.alert("Successfully update.");
            document.location.href ='list_sale_update.php';
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Error editing list. Please contact system administrator.");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>

    <center><h1><font size="5" face="verdana" >Listing Modification</font></h1></center>


    <?php
    $conn = oci_connect("username","password","database")
    or die("Couldn't logon.");

            if (empty($_POST["check"]))
            {
                $query = "SELECT P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET,P.PTY_POSTCODE, P.PTY_SUBURB, P.PTY_CITY, T.P_TYPE_NAME,
                      L.LIST_PRICE, L.SALE_PRICE,
                      C.SELLER_FNAME, C.SELLER_LNAME, 
                      L.AVAILABILITY
              FROM    PROPERTY_TYPE T, PROPERTY P, CUSTOMER C, LISTINGS L  
              WHERE  P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID(+)
              AND    L.SELLER_ID = C.SELLER_ID(+)
              AND    P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID(+)
              ORDER BY P.PTY_ID";

                $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
                oci_execute($stmt);
                ?>

                <form method="post"
                      action="list_avai_update.php">
                    <table border="2" cellpadding="5" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <th><b> Property ID</th>
                            <th><b> Address</th>
                            <th><b> Property Type</th>
                            <th><b> Seller Name</th>
                            <th><b> Available?</th>
                            <th><b> Listing Price</th>
                            <th><b> Sale Price</th>
                            <th><b> Checkbox</th>
                        </tr>


                        <?php
                        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt)) {
                            ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt, "PTY_ID"); ?></td>

                                <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt, "PTY_UNITNUM"), " ", oci_result($stmt, "PTY_STREET"),
                                    ", ", oci_result($stmt, "PTY_SUBURB"), ", ", oci_result($stmt, "PTY_CITY"),
                                    ", ", oci_result($stmt, "PTY_POSTCODE"); ?></td>

                                <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt, "P_TYPE_NAME"); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt, "SELLER_FNAME"), " ", oci_result($stmt, "SELLER_LNAME"); ?></td>

                                <td>
                                    Yes<input type="radio" name = "<?php echo oci_result($stmt, "PTY_ID"); ?>"
                                              value="1"<?php echo (oci_result($stmt, "AVAILABILITY") == '1') ? 'checked' : '' ?>><br>
                                    No <input type="radio" name = "<?php echo oci_result($stmt, "PTY_ID"); ?>"
                                              value="0"<?php echo (oci_result($stmt, "AVAILABILITY") == '0') ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                                </td>

                                <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt, "LIST_PRICE"); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt, "SALE_PRICE"); ?></td>

                                <td align="center">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]"
                                           value="<?php echo oci_result($stmt, "PTY_ID"); ?>">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                <br><br>

                    <center>
                        <td><input type="submit" style="height:50px; width:200px" value="Confirm Update"
                                   onclick="return(confirm());"></td>                  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="button" style="height:50px; width:200px" value="Return"
                                   OnClick="window.location='listing_multi.php'">
                    </center>

                </form>
                <?php
                oci_free_statement($stmt);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($_POST["check"] as $pty_id)
                {
                    $query = "UPDATE LISTINGS 
                      set AVAILABILITY = " . $_POST[$pty_id] . " 
                      WHERE PTY_ID ='" . $pty_id . "'";
                    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
                    oci_execute($stmt);
                    header("location: list_avai_update.php");


                }

            }

    oci_close($conn);
    ?>

<br><br>
<?php

$filename=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];

?>
<a href="displaysource.php?filename=<?php echo $filename;?>" target="_blank"><img src="images/client.png "/> </a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this issue you are talking about?

Comment: [`oci_bind_by_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php): "_Binds a PHP variable `variable` to the Oracle bind variable placeholder `bv_name`. Binding is important for Oracle database performance **and also as a way to avoid SQL Injection security issues**._"

Comment: Its about javascript window alert not triggered in php code, if you read my question. @vlaz

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the reminder! I will keep that in mind. Now regarding my question, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're defining a global function named "confirm", which will replace the existing window.confirm().  Inside your custom function, you then attempt call "window.confirm()" - BUT, since you replaced it, you are actually now calling your OWN function. This results in an infinite loop, causing...get ready for it...a "Stack Overflow" error :)  Rename your function to something other than "confirm" (but continue to call window.confirm() inside of it, of course)

Comment: ...which I did not encounter. I am having some question with javascript only. But thanks for sharing

Comment: You actually might not (probably not) get a "stack overflow" error, because you're not actually allocating any memory in your function (and thus can't overflow your stack memory).  Nevertheless, you are *definitely* overwriting/redefining window.confirm() and calling your own function recursively/infinitely.  You must rename your "confirm" function to something else, like "myConfirm" or some other name not already on the "window" object.

Comment: Oh! You are right! Now it works perfectly fine. Thank you Jeff@:D